# vtk value at x,y,z point

Tags: c++, vtk

I have a `vtk` file which maps temperature in 3 dimensions. I would like to determine the temperature at a given x, y, z point. I will use the following code in order to load the `vtk` file ([Reading .vtk file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300310/reading-vtk-file)):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  // simply set filename here (oh static joy)
  std::string inputFilename = "setYourPathToVtkFileHere";

  // Get all data from the file
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericDataObjectReader> reader =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericDataObjectReader>::New();
  reader->SetFileName(inputFilename.c_str());
  reader->Update();

  // All of the standard data types can be checked and obtained like this:
  if (reader->IsFilePolyData()) 
  {
    std::cout << "output is a polydata" << std::endl;
    vtkPolyData* output = reader->GetPolyDataOutput();
    std::cout << "output has " << output->GetNumberOfPoints() << "     points." << std::endl;
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, when searching through the extensive list of methods in the `vtk` library I cant find the appropriate function to extract a value at a specific location. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

The proper way to retrieve a scalar value at a given position depends on two questions:

1. How is your data laid out and
2. From which position do you want to retrieve an attribute

Concerning the **data layout** there are two main layouts:

- Structured: The data resides in a uniform grid
- Unstructured: The point samples are arbitrary

Concerning the **position** you can have two situations:

- Query at a sample position: You ask for a point that is directly a sample in your dataset
- Query at an arbitrary position: You ask for a point that is somewhere in your domain but does not neccessarily coincide with a sample of your data.

Independent of the data layout, to retrieve the data at a sample position (i.e. a sample of your original data set) you can use the vtkPointLocator class. Use the class as follows (untested):

```
// Build locator object
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPointLocator> locator = vtkPointLocator::New();
locator->SetDataSet(polyData);
locator->BuildLocator();
// Define query position
double pt[3] = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3};
// Get the ID of the point that is closest to the query position
vtkIdType id = locator->FindClosestPoint(pt);
// Retrieve the first attribute value from this point
double value = polyData->GetPointData()->GetScalars()->GetTuple(id, 0);
```

This will give you the point value of the closest sample of your data.
**Note that this will not give you the explicit position of the point in the data set as this is implicitly encoded in the variable id**. To retrieve the actual position of the closest point, you can write:

```
double *dataPt = polyData->GetPoint(id);
```

If you want to retrieve data at an arbitrary position of your domain you will need some way of interpolation.
Here, the data layout is important.

- For structured data you can first convert your data to a vtkImage and then perform queries on it. If you want to retrieve an interpolated attribute using linear or cubic schemes you can add a vtkImageInterpolator in your filter chain and then retrieve a point using the GetScalarComponentAsDouble method.
- For unstructured data you should first decide on an interpolation scheme. vtk has various filters to reconstruct continuous data from data samples. Options include Delaunay triangulation/tetrahedrization (vtkDelaunay2D, vtkDelaunay3D) , as well as the Shepard method (vtkShepardMethod). Either method will give you a new data set with possibilities to query arbitrary points. If you want to retrieve the scalar attributes for a (batch of) points without actually reconstructing a complete data set you can also look at the vtkProbeFilter.

Comment: Do you have to use setActiveScalar("temp") before if there are multiple scalars available?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first extract the polyData from the reader. Then, store the points via `vtkPolyData::getPoints` into a `vtksmartPointer<vtkPoints>`.
To finish, create a `std::vector` of a custom struct and store them while iterating over your vtkPoints.

Here's some code to illustrate :

```
#include <vtkDataArray.h>
#include <vtkDataSet.h>
#include <vtkGenericDataObjectReader.h>
#include <vtkPointLocator.h>
#include <vtkPointData.h>
#include <vtkPolyData.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkStructuredGrid.h>
#include <string>


struct Pnt {
    double x_, y_, z_;
    Pnt(double x, double y, double z) : x_(x), y_(y), z_(z) {}
};

    int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  // Ensure a filename was specified
  if(argc != 2)
    {
    std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " InputFilename" << endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

  // simply set filename here (oh static joy)
  std::string inputFilename = "setYourPathToVtkFileHere";

  // Get all data from the file
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericDataObjectReader> reader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericDataObjectReader>::New();
  reader->SetFileName(inputFilename.c_str());
  reader->Update();

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> polydata = reader->GetPolyDataOutput();
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> vtk_points = polydata->GetPoints();

  std::vector<Pnt> my_points;
  for (int i = 0; i < vtk_points->GetNumberOfPoints(); i++){
      const auto pnt = vtk_points->GetPoint(i);
      my_points.emplace_back(pnt[0], pnt[1], pnt[2]);
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And here is the version with the vtkPointLocator mentionned in QnD's answer :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Ensure a filename was specified
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " InputFilename" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // simply set filename here (oh static joy)
    std::string inputFilename = "setYourPathToVtkFileHere";

    // Get all data from the file
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericDataObjectReader> reader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericDataObjectReader>::New();
    reader->SetFileName(inputFilename.c_str());
    reader->Update();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> polydata = reader->GetPolyDataOutput();

    //Building locator
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPointLocator> locator = vtkPointLocator::New();
    locator->SetDataSet(polydata);
    locator->BuildLocator();

    //Finding point
    const double pt[3] = { 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 };
    vtkIdType id = locator->FindClosestPoint(pt);
    double pnt_found[3];
    polydata->GetPointData()->GetScalars()->GetTuple(id, pnt_found);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And the CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(GenericDataObjectReader)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

add_executable(GenericDataObjectReader MACOSX_BUNDLE GenericDataObjectReader)

if(VTK_LIBRARIES)
  target_link_libraries(GenericDataObjectReader ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
else()
  target_link_libraries(GenericDataObjectReader vtkHybrid vtkWidgets)
endif()
```

Please let me know if I need to do any specific action to correctly credit the other answer. I'm new and don't know all the specifics yet.

Comment: cmake CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Thanks dutiona. I apologise if the following follow-up question is mindless, however I am a complete newbie to the VTK library. I have tried the following code and make method (and a number of variants) and still get compile errors. I assume I'm not including the right headers or adding the correct libraries in the CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: Hi, I'll try to get some time to fully write a working example at work tomorow. I've not compiled vtk at home and it takes a lot of time to do so.